# JSC::HEAP::releaseAccessSlow() crashing app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on an app with React-native. My problem is that my app crash some times.

I am not able to identify the source of my problem, it seems to happen randomly.

Here are the only logs that I get :
[image: Error]

Does anyone has an idea of what is happening ?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @MartinMlostek No, I did not.